# Firestore Security Rule for querying - Issue with rule list

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to prevent querying from a collection with the following security rule:

```
match /routes/{routeID} {
   allow list, get: if false;
   allow delete: if false; 
   allow update, create;
}
```

And the following Java (Android) code:

```
 Query query = mRoutesColRef
    .limit(50)
    .whereEqualTo("uid", mFirebaseUser.getUid())
    .orderBy("route_end_timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

 FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Route> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Route>()
    .setQuery(query, Route.class)
    .build();

 mAdapter = new RidesProfileAdapter(options);

 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 mAdapter.startListening();

 query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
         if (value != null) {
             // do stuff
         }
         else {
             if (error != null)
                 logEvent(mActivity, "e", "Error while addSnapshotListener in profile: " + error.getMessage());
         }
     }
 });
```

In the snapshotListener, I get, as expected, the following error:

> E/Debugging: Error while addSnapshotListener in profile: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

However, the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and the FirestoreRecyclerOptions keep indeed fetching new documents in case the user adds any. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent querying from a collection"? Who should be allowed and who shouldn't be allowed? What would like to prevent from reading? A single document or all the documents in the collection?

Comment: "Prevent querying from a collection" means forbidding retrieval of documents via a query from a given collection. The actual use case is that users who created a route can retrieve only the documents associated with the route they created (for ex. 'allow list: if request.query.limit <= 50 && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;'). I have no issues regarding this use case. However, I was experimenting with the rules and I noticed the behaviour described in my question (pls see also my comment below).

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the same query (or otherwise read the route data) on this device before introducing the restriction on `list` and `get` in your security rule? If so, the data might be in the cache and the query might get it from there. If that is the case, delete and reinstall the app to get rid of the cached data (there is no other way to get a client to unsee data it has already seen).

Comment: By deleting and reinstalling the app, indeed the query cannot fetch any routes. However, when running the same query without deleting and reinstalling the app, I was expecting to see only cached data (i.e. routes created before introducing the restriction on list), whereas I can see also those documents created - after -introducing the restriction on list.

Comment: I would expect the same indeed, that you'd only see the data before you locked down the list. The query should at any point only be able to get data from the server that it is authorized for by your rules. For example: if you disable disk caching, you should never be able to get any data on the client. Is that really nor happening for you?

Comment: I checked, double-checked... and while the SnapshotListener behaves as expected, the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter responds to new documents added after the addition of the rule.